# How can my SQL query be optimized?

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I have a problem with a quite slowish MYSQL query. I'm building an AJAX menu with PHP and performance is really an issue. The query takes about 0,5 sec to complete, and i don't know how to optimize it.

**The SQL query :**

```
SELECT M.nom_mat, M.id_mat, M.rang, SC.nom_sous_cat, SC.id_sous_cat, C.nom_cat,M.id_cat
FROM besson_mat M
LEFT OUTER JOIN besson_lien_mat LM ON M.id_mat = LM.id_mat
LEFT OUTER JOIN besson_sous_cat SC ON SC.id_sous_cat = LM.id_sous_cat
LEFT OUTER JOIN besson_cat C ON C.id_cat = SC.id_cat
WHERE M.en_ligne = '1'
AND M.lg = 'fr'
AND (
M.id_cat = '28'
OR M.id_cat = '29'
)
OR (
SC.id_sous_cat = '37'
OR SC.id_sous_cat = '42'
OR SC.id_sous_cat = '43'
OR SC.id_sous_cat = '44'
)
ORDER BY C.id_cat ASC , SC.id_sous_cat ASC , M.rang ASC
```

Thanks for your help, I'll update my question if you need more details.

**FINAL EDIT**

The extra parentheses in the WHERE clause were the cause of the problem. Now my Query takes about 0.0718 sec to complete, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you might consider putting indexes on any of the columns used in your JOINS, WHERE clauses, and ORDER BY clauses.

If that doesn't help, use your database development interface to do an explain plan on the query to see where it's bogging down.

You might try putting the results of your Explain Plan here.

Comment: Also, it appears you might have a syntax issue. Are you sure you don't want an extra set of parentheses around the final two parts of the where clause?

Comment: Thanks, the extra parentheses were the cause of my problem. Now my query is blazing fast.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `column IN(id1, id2, id3,...)` syntax instead of that many ORs.

Second, Mysql has a `EXPLAIN <statement>` command which gives you some hints, what it does and how you could optimize your query (use index, redesign the joins etc)
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: +1 for `EXPLAIN` command.  I think internally the `IN()` and the `or` will be optimized to about the same (In other words, I don't think the gain will be much if at all).  But `EXPLAIN` should show why it's slow...

Comment: Oh, from a readability standpoint, the `IN()` is LOADS better.  And IMHO I tend to favor readability over length (and performance, unless it's known to be a bottleneck)...

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, i tried an EXPLAIN on my query, but i don't understand the results. Can you provide a link on how to read it?

Comment: The link you provided was enough, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do Join only to filter, you can use exists or not exists clause, it's better.

Maybe remove your order by clause and do your sorting in your app.

and you can also ad some index in your id column, lg and en_ligne

Avec plaisir et bienvenu sur SO